# How to embed elements in React Components, make it like the Container

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I want build component like this :

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component {
    render(){

        return <div width="1000">{xxx }</div>
    }
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
<MyContainer><xxx></xxx></MyContainer>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: This just adds unnecessary complexity to an already complex system. It is more readable and traceable if you embed that `<div>` inside the component itself

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this.props.children.  That would go into the container component.  Any nested elements in the container tag would be rendered into this.props.children.